# JQuery event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game, below is the code that I've set up to have playerX mark a box, then switch to player O. 
Using $.on('click') to listen for which box was clicked. 
I'm getting what I think is event bubbling. 
Every time one box gets clicked, the next box produces an exponential reaction, and so on.
I tried e.stopPropogation but it blocks the next move.

How do I stop the reaction flood?

```
    function playX () {


     $box.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(this);
        var a = e.target.dataset.index;
        b[a] = 'X';
        $(this).text('X');
        playO();     
  })
 }
    function playO() {

    $box.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(this);
        var b = e.target.dataset.index;
        b[b] = 'O';
        $(this).text('O');

        playX();

})
}
```

Here's the link to all of it
http://jsfiddle.net/shallak/fdctcvdt/

(I'm also using a css framework, Materialize)

Comment: You shouldn't be binding the event each time playX or playO is called.. each time another handler is registered which causes the "exponential" behaviour you're experiencing. The quickest solution to your problem is use "$box.one(...)" instead of "$box.on(...)" ( This will bind the event once and the clear the handler )

Comment: As @elad.chen stated, you only need to bind the click event once. moreover it's better to have 1 function and just change the code if it's X or O.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be binding the event each time playX or playO is called.. each time another handler is registered which causes the "exponential" behaviour you're experiencing. The quickest solution to your problem is use "$box.one(...)" instead of "$box.on(...)" ( This will bind the event once and the clear the handler )

Anyway, I took the liberty of refining your implementation:

```
var results = ( function() {
    var currentPlayer = "X"
    var b = new Array(9) // Assumed 'b' was array of played moves

    // "$box" - make sure this one is available by this point
    // or just set it accordingly. 
    $box.on( "click", function(e) {
        var index = e.target.dataset.index;

        // make sure the current index was never played
        if ( index === undefined ) {
           if ( currentPlayer === "X" ) {
               b[index] = "X"
               currentPlayer = "O"
           }
            else {
               b[index] = "O"
               currentPlayer = "X"
            }
        }
    } )

    // Return a reference to the array which holds each squre value 
    return b;
} () )
```

Comment: Thank you elad and Stuart, very helpful. I thought that .one() would work, too but I'm getting the same errors. I also tried to use Stuart's fix and modified it to make it work (adding the text 'x' or 'o') but it's still not totally working. I'm new to js so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: When I use .one(), it did not stop the bubbling. When I used Stuart's refinement, I couldn't get the text in the box, though I tried. I understand the idea behind Stuart's code, but I was not successful in making it work.